# REST API to create multiple groups in gitlab at once

Tags: gitlab-api, gitlab-ee

I have installed GitLab EE (11.4.7-ee). I'm trying to create mulitplr groups using REST API.

```
https://testserver/gitlab/api/v4/groups
```

Post Data:

```
[
    { "name": "test1", "path": "test1" },
    { "name": "test2", "path": "test2" },
    { "name": "test3", "path": "test3" }
    ]
```

Error Message :

> { "error": "name is missing, path is missing" }

How to create many groups in one GitLab Group create Rest API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written the python script to craete multiple group in gitlab

```
import requests
import json
import urllib3

with open('./jfmjson.json', 'r') as f:
    jfm_dict = json.load(f)

for jfm in jfm_dict:
    print(jfm['path'])
    gitlab_url = "https://testserver/gitlab/api/v4/groups"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'pxpR3sehJ-xYzz61XxAs'}
    data = {'name': jfm['path'], 'path': jfm['path'], 'description': jfm['name']}
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    r = requests.post(gitlab_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)
```